# What is the deal with Providence?

Tags: risk-of-rain

At the begining of Risk of Rain, Providence (final boss) shows up and causes your ship to crash (leading to the rest of the game). Once you get to the UES Contact Light again, and fight your way through it, you find and battle Providence. But, when you win, he says:

> You... monster...

Why does he say that, and why did he attack the ship you were on? In some twisted way, was I the villian?

Comment: There is no definitive answer, but it seems somewhat likely that you are in fact the villain.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As Jake said in a comment, there doesn't seem to be a definitive answer, but I thought I'd summarise what I found in an answer.

There is a lot of speculation [on the wiki](http://riskofrain.wikia.com/wiki/Providence) as well as [on reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/riskofrain/comments/2kn1ea/what_do_you_think_the_ending_messages_mean_for/). It all seems to point towards the theory that you're actually the evil guy committing genocide on this poor planet, which the Providence tries to protect. Notice that the Providence's "subtitle" is *Bulwark of the Weak*. Also, if you read through the monster logs, in several of them it is mentioned that most of the "monsters" all seem very social and happy and not aggressive at all until [whoever wrote the log] comes closer.

Some of the posts mention the item logs as well, and interpret them such that your transport vessel was actually looting the planet, which is why the Providence destroys the ship [in the intro](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SJz8Xk6c_ok).

Most of the endings (see the reddit post) also indicate that you leave the planet as a soulless killer. So while you might have initially really just fought to survive (although even by that point you might have been the evil guy who looted the planet), by the end of it, you're just the murdering innocent inhabitants of the planet.

I think it's a really nice perspective on these kinds of games, because essentially that's what you're doing in many games, but you're always presented as the hero getting rid of evil hordes.

Comment: Doesn't the intro video imply many of the monsters were on the ship (potentially prisoners) ?  And thus are "raining" down and attacking their former captor.  Just speculation.